Bijection between minimal $C^*$-tensor product representations, and pairs of its correspondants restriction representations.
Let $A$ and $B$ be two $C^*$-algebras, and let $A \odot B $ be the algebraic tensor product of $A$ and $B$ as a vector space.
The vector space $A \odot B$ is a $^*$-algebra defined by the following ring multiplication and involution,
$$ (a \otimes b) \dot (a' \otimes b') = aa' \otimes bb' \ \ , \ \ ( a \otimes b )^* = a^* \otimes b^* $$
Let define the minimal tensor norm on $ A \odot B $ as follows,
$ \forall x = \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_j \odot b_j \in A \odot B $, $$ ||x||_{\mathrm{min}} = \sup \{ || \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n} \pi_1 (a_j) \otimes \pi_{2} (b_j) || \ \ \pi_i \ : \ A_i \to \mathcal{B} ( \mathcal{H_i } ) \ \ \text{(non degenerate) representations }\} $$
$|| \cdot ||_{\mathrm{min}} $ is a norm, and we can define the minimal ( or spatial ) tensor product $C^*$-algebra, $$ A \otimes_{\mathrm{min}} B = \overline{A \odot B}^{|| \cdot ||_{\mathrm{min}}} $$
My question is,
Given two representations, $ \pi_i \ : \ A_i \to \mathcal{B} ( \mathcal{H}_i ) $, $ i = 1,2 $, there is an induced representation $ \pi_1 \otimes \pi_2 \ : \ A \otimes_{\mathrm{min}} B \to \mathcal{B}( \mathcal{H}_{1} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{2}) $ such that, $ (\pi_1 \otimes \pi_2) ( a \otimes b ) = \pi_1 (a) \otimes \pi_2 (b) $. What about the inverse ? Given a spatial tensor product representation $ \pi \ : \ A \otimes_{\mathrm{min}} B \to \mathcal{B}( \mathcal{H}_{1} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{2}) $, when can we define restriction representations, $ \pi_{|A_{i}} \ : \ A_i \to \mathcal{B} ( \mathcal{H}_i ) $, $ i = 1,2 $, such that, $ \pi = \pi_{|A} \otimes \pi_{|B} $ ?
In other words, is there a natural bijection between non degenerate representations $ \pi \ : \ A \otimes_{\mathrm{min}} B \to \mathcal{B}( \mathcal{H}_{1} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{2}) $, and pairs of commutings non degenerate representations, $ \pi_1 \ : \ A \to \mathcal{B} ( \mathcal{H}_1 ) $, and, $ \pi_2 \ : \ B \to \mathcal{B} ( \mathcal{H}_2 ) $ ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

No. If $A = B$ is commutative and represented on $H$, say, then $\pi(a \otimes b)h = abh$ is a well-defined representation of $A \otimes_\min B$ on $H$. Obviously there is no reason why this representation can be decomposed as a tensor product. (In most cases it clearly can’t.)
Just to be specific, say $A = B = C([0, 1])$ is represented in the standard way on $L^2([0, 1])$. Let $x \in C([0, 1])$ be the identity function $[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$. If $\pi = \pi_1 \otimes \pi_2$. As $\pi|_{A \otimes 1}$ is faithful, $\pi_1$ must be faithful. Similarly, $\pi_2$ must be faithful. But then $\pi_1 \otimes \pi_2$ is faithful. But $\pi(x \otimes 1) = \pi(1 \otimes x)$ while $x \otimes 1 \neq 1 \otimes x$, so $\pi \neq \pi_1 \otimes \pi_2$.

Thank you Sir.  :-)
